# Solving $|x|^2=\sqrt{2}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\xi_8] $

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is there a solution of the equation $|x|^2=\sqrt{2}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\xi_8]$, where | | means the complex absolute value? In general, can I solve the equations of the form $|x|^2=c$ in each ring of cyclotomic integers $\mathbb{Z}[\xi_n]$ where $c\in \mathbb{Z}[\xi_n]$? Are there any universal algorithms for these problems?